# How do I tar the certain files of a directory without retaining the directory structure?

Tags: tar, gzip

I typically do :

tar czf $directory_path/file_${1}.tar.gz --directory=$specified_path/ *${1}.csv .

What if I just want to include only certain files of a directory, but not the directory itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd [dir]; tar cz ./* >x.tgz
```

or

```
cd [dir]; tar cz file1 file2 >x.tgz
```